# Increase matplotlib figure DPI in Jupyter Notebooks, but for export to PDF only

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I want to increase matplotlib figure DPI in Jupyter Notebooks, but for export to PDF only. I change matplotlib figure DPI with the following:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
```

However, this makes matplotlib figures large in the notebook (bigger than the screen). I teach classes from notebooks and would like notebook figures low resolution (so they fit on laptop screens) and PDF figures high resolution (I export notebooks to PDFs to view them on the learning management system, Canvas).

I could comment the line above during class, then un-comment it before exporting the notebook to PDF. But is there a less manual solution?

I tried `plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300` instead, but this did not provide high DPI PDF figures. I don't see `nbconvert` command-line options to change matplotlib DPI. Is there a less manual way to get low DPI figures in notebooks and high DPI figures in PDFs? I'm open to different workflows.

Comment: PDF is a vector format. Dpi does matter, but only if you rasterize an artist.  In that case savefig.dpi should work, and if it doesn’t you can try fig.savefig(…,dpi=300)

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks. When I export to PDF, I don't explicitly save my figures. `nbconvert` runs my notebook, creates a LaTeX file and figures, then compiles to PDF. I thought that changing `figure.dpi` would affect the `nbconvert`'s figure generation, but it does not (as far as I know).